# Windows Enterprise Edition: Is it possible to undelete a service that has been marked for deletion?

Tags: windows-services

Somehow, a windows service installed on a remote machine that we rely on has been marked for deletion.  We don't know how or why it has been marked for deletion.  Is there a way to unmark it for deletion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The service is still running, but has been marked to be deleted upon next boot.

Open the machine's Registry (using *Remote Registry* if needed), find the service's subkey under `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services`, and delete the value named `DeleteFlag`.

The service will still appear as disabled, and operations on it will fail, but this should be fixed by a reboot. (But to be safe, export the service's subkey from registry, so you could reimport it afterwards.)

Comment: I don't see a delete flag, but I think it was there at one time. Here's what happened: This service exists on two machines. On machine A (where it's marked for deletion), I deleted the subkey entirely (before I did that, I do believe I saw DeleteFlag). I then went to machine B, exported the service info to a reg file, and imported it into machine A's registry.  Did I just blow my chances at unmarking this for deletion?

Comment: @oscilatingcretin: As long as `DeleteFlag` does not exist, the service should be okay.

Comment: Well, it's still telling us that the service has been marked for deletion every time we attempt to make a call to it, so something's borked up somewhere =\

Comment: @oscil - as grawity pointed out the service is not running, your problems won't be fixed, until a restart.

Comment: The deletion flag is kept in the service manager's memory too, that's why it fails. But the in-memory flag will go away after a reboot. The service won't get actually deleted if you removed the registry flag.

Comment: I was hoping to not have to wait until a reboot =\.  We don't have the ability to reboot the remote server and would get our hands smacked pretty hard if we did.  I guess your answer is the correct answer, so I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0):

No, it has been emptied so the service information is gone. Restore a back-up...